# How to prove that $p\models \varphi$ where $p$ is an atom and $\varphi$ is some well formed formula?

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus

I am given that $\varphi$ is a well formed formula which only has atom variables and the logic symbol $\rightarrow$,
and I need to prove that there exists an atom $p$ in $\varphi$ such that $p\models \varphi$.

I'm having trouble understanding this so i can't begin to prove anything but i was thinking to go with the structural induction ,the base case i understand perfectly when $\varphi$ is an atom but beyond the base case i can't go on ,for simple a example when $\varphi=q\rightarrow p$ what am i supposed to be noticing?

Comment: Try drawing a truth table for $q \to p$.

Comment: Still not seeing it sorry my fault,I think I'm misunderstanding the $\models$ sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just let $p$ be the last atom that appears in $\varphi$.

Comment: Then how do I go on from that ,im sorry I think I'm not having a clear idea on what $\models$ means

Answer (score 1):

Structural induction sounds exactly right.

**Hint**: If $p$ is an atom such that $p\vDash\psi$, then you also have $p\vDash\varphi\to\psi$.

Comment: @user3133165: That's pretty unreadable. You seem to have stopped writing English words halfway through your text, so it's impossible to tell how all the symbols are supposed to relate to each other.

Comment: I will only try to write my induction step so far :By taking $\varphi_1$ to be a well formed formula that satisfies the condition ,then I'll let $\varphi=\varphi_1 \rightarrow p$ since $q \models \varphi_1$ where $q$ is an atom in $\varphi_1$. I'm now trying to reach a conclusion from here

Comment: @user3133165: You can't "let $\varphi=\varphi_1\to p$" -- when you're writing the induction step _you don't choose the form of the formula you're proving things about_. They'll be given to you by the adversary, so a step where you only consider the special case that the second operand to $\to$ is an atom, is not a complete induction step.

Comment: So I'm looking to prove two cases in the induction step ?

Comment: @user3133165: In the formulation of structural induction I'm used to, you need to prove two cases: (a) where $\varphi$ has the form $p$ for some propositional variable $p$, and (b) where $\varphi$ has the form $\psi_1\to\psi_2$ for some formulas $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$. In case (b) you're allowed to assume that the claim you want to prove already holds about $\psi_1$, and holds about $\psi_2$.

Comment: "Structural induction sounds exactly right."  I'm fairly sure that structural induction is not needed to prove this.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to use structural induction for this exercise.  However, it's not necessary.

Note two things:

1. Even conditional ends with an atom.
2. ((p$\rightarrow$q)$\rightarrow$(q$\rightarrow$(p$\rightarrow$q))) holds.

Thus, given any conditional, we have a constructive method by which to produce such an atom p in φ such that p⊨φ.